# Предсказание временного ряда по алгоритму машинного обучения или нейросети?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xcM2KNkLQ5P9dd8INU6OuOKfvY1gKeQp
Есть данные из 1С. Нужно предсказать объем продаж на неделю.Помогите разобраться, как это сделать. Была попытка нейросетью - не вышло https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1RCX0HwFLAa2MPOEhx9Srdh6xl_szTl6q
Нашла идею Воронцова через алгоритмы машинного обучения.Но с чего начать непонятно. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u3lhVV3wAKk
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RdTxLXmbvjY&t=315s

Comment: Чем отличается "нейросетью" от "машинного обучения"? я совсем не в теме тренда отмывания денег на нейросетях, и не вижу между фразами ничего что в корне бы отличало подходы =)

Comment: Напишите, кто в теме отличить машинное обучение от нейросети

Comment: Пишу - Нейросеть это частный случай машинного обучения, т.е. Машинное обучение это огромная группа "алгоритмов", в которую в том числе входит более мелкая - Нейросети. Вы думаете мой вопрос возник на ровном месте от незнания терминологии - вы заблуждаетесь =).

Comment: я бы начинал [отсюда](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-time-series-forecasting-models-a2fa7a358fcb)...)

Comment: Владимир, зачем писать тут прописные истины, которые понятны

Comment: Ближе к теме скорее эта статья, когда происходит оценка 
конкретной модели на сколько качественно она предсказывает https://habr.com/ru/post/207160/

Comment: @svil, приведенная вами статья - это один из самых примитивных алгоритмов, который не учитывает "сезонность" во временных рядах. Практически все известные мне популярные алгоритмы предсказаний по временным рядам учитывают компонент "сезонности". Некоторые дополнительно учитывают праздники

Comment: Да, но мне надо руку на этом набить, а потом уже буду пробовать алгоритмы https://biznesbooks.com/components/com_jshopping/files/demo_products/lukashin-yu-p-adaptivnye-metody-prognozirovaniya.pdf

Comment: Я что-то потерял нить. В чем вопрос? Подсказать отличие понятий "нейросеть" и "МО" -  так сказали, но для вас это "прописные истины". Подсказать, как прогнозируются временные ряды? Так по теме есть миллион источников, найти их не проблема. Рассказать, как оцениваются модели - это только один из подразделов МО.  Дать примеры использования временных рядов для предсказания продаж- тоже недостатка информации вроде нет,ну первый попавшийся: https://towardsdatascience.com/an-end-to-end-project-on-time-series-analysis-and-forecasting-with-python-4835e6bf050b Уточните все-таки,что же вас интересует?

Comment: @svil Ставьте пожалуйста собаку перед именем, иначе нет уведомлений. Потому что вопрос про сравнение "круглого" и "синего" звучит как минимум странно =) Одно не исключает другого, но вы ставите между сущностями противопоставление.

Comment: @svil Посмотрел ноутбук в колабе. Так вроде работают всякие разные методы, которые там пробуются - и линейная регрессия и прочие. А что нейросети на всякое ругаются - так для работы с GPU и CUDA драйверами надо настройки всякие делать, вот тут что-то похожее на вашу ошибку нашёл, но не факт, что ответ вам поможет: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48493294/tensorflow-op-type-not-registered-cudnnrnn